# Get Eloquent table data from a nested loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on a student consultancy project. In the website header's country option, I am showing the value as, when the country is clicked, it will show the subcontinent and countries under the subcontinent. However, there are some popular countries that students are familiar with but unfamiliar with their subcontinent. So that's why those countries will be created under the subcontinent. So, for example, Australia is in Oceania, but Australia is in the subcontinent.

The subcontinent is in one-to-many relations with the country, and countries are in one-to-many relations with the university. So if I create Australia, I have to add something in countries to find the university under Australia. So I am adding one country Australia under subcontinent Australia. That way, I can access the university.

However, the main problem is I don't want to show that in the header's country drop-down menu. So I am trying to select it differently in the controller, which subcontinent doesn't have the same country name under it. So I will pass it with a different variable.

**Controller**

```
$dis = '';
$concatenated = collect();

foreach ($divisions as $key => $value) {
    $dis = DB::table('subcontinents')
        ->where('subcontinent_name', '!=', $value->country_name)->get();
    foreach ($concatenated as $k => $val) {
        if ($val->subcontinent_name != $dis->subcontinent_name)
            $concatenated = $concatenated->concat($dis);
    }
}

dd($concatenated);
```

I created the country as a division. I am selecting subcontinents where the name is not the same. It gives output like this: `[output][1]`. So I tried to `concat` once if the name didn't exist previously. Now it's showing a null value. How can I solve this? Any kind of idea will also be helpful.

Comment: `$dis` is collection,`$dis->subcontinent_name` is null，the if condition is always true.

Comment: How can I push the subcontinent name once? should I use another loop for $dis?